# How do I get the Maverick Hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2016

I have a question regarding the [Maverick Hat](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/maverick), which states that in order to gain it, one must:

> answer a -3 question;
>   later +3

I have two answers in my mind.

Is this for answering a −3 question first and waiting till it gets upvoted to +3? Or do I need to answer a −3 question in the beginning and answer a +3 question later.

Or there is some other scenario that gives the hat?

> If you click on the hat itself, you do get an expanded explanation:

[image: answer a +5 to a -3 question that goes to +3]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you click on the hat itself, you do get an expanded explanation:

> answer +5 a -3 question that goes to +3

So:

1. Find a question that is scored -3.
2. Answer it.
3. Wait until your answer is scored +5 *and* the question is scored +3.
4. <s>PROFIT!</s> HAT!

Comment: These hats are so incredibly complicated :(

Comment: @AndrewL Yeah i am also finding it so complicated.

Comment: @AndrewL that's part of the fun. Hats which are trivial to get are less fun, at least for many people. :)

Comment: What if I happen to answer a question that was -4 and is now +1 , if it reaches +2 is that OK?

Comment: @Mari-LouA No. It needs to be at -3 or lower and then get up to +3 or higher. The criteria is not to receive 6 upvotes after the answer.

Comment: Ahh, man... bugger. Shattered I am, shattered... Merry Xmas, by the way.

Comment: I really appreciated your answering my request in the comments, it saved me from the bother of writing a question about that specific issue, but... as for placing a bounty, not 100% ethical, I admit but these are hard times, would the resulting upvotes (because the question has already earned +8) count? If instead you think I should make this into a question, I'll do that.