# Maverick hat not awarded during bounty

Tags: discussion, bounties, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

This question is intertwined with an earlier one I posted

[Maverick Hat BOUNTY rules?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289119/maverick-hat-bounty-rules)

I answered a -3 [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/107611/a-single-word-for-someone-who-spends-their-wealth-very-foolishly) on January 1 and on the same day  I placed a bounty on it. The bounty, which I cannot award to myself, is 100 points because users who have posted an answer cannot offer a bounty for less than that amount. My answer has earned +9, a new answer has earned +4 but it was posted 3 January, I cannot tell if he has won the Maverick hat because I think he has opted out of Winter bash (*stunned silence*).

[image]

The question is now +3 and ....

[image]

I still haven't got the hat. (This is the second time it has earned +3 but after five hours it earned a negative vote and it was back to -2.)

Obviously I'm missing something here, but I can't think what it is. BTW I did not edit the original question, the upvotes and downvotes it has received belong to the OP they have nothing to do with me. Personally, I quite like the question but it has attracted a total of 7 downvotes and 10 upvotes so far.

- Why haven't I got the Maverick Hat?

Can someone explain what I must have done wrong? Did I break the rules? Or is this a bug in the system?

Thanks.

Comment: Perhaps you didn't get the hat because one of the question votes was yours. Maybe it needs another upvote

Comment: @Eran Okaaay I thought it might be that but there's no information saying saying a user cannot upvote a question they have answered. Aaaaand, I only upvoted it about two days ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is working by-design.

If you've answered the question, your vote doesn't count towards the total score for the hat.  Many of the hats exclude self-actions, for example we exclude self-answers on the Snaphat.  In order for you to get the hat for this post, it would need to get the 3+ score without a vote by you.

Comment: OK. Got it. Thanks. But next year, maybe that clause should be added or made clearer.

Comment: I just got the hat even though it's still +3 there must have been a few minutes when it was +4 when someone downvoted it. Anyway, thanks :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, about 7 minutes.